# XGBoostError: basic_string::resize

Tags: python, machine-learning, error-handling, xgboost

I want to implement a xgboost model. For this, I have already performed hyperparameter tuning via `skopt.BayesSearchCV` as you can see in the following code:

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor 
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from skopt.space import Real, Categorical, Integer

SEED = 8

xgb_clf = XGBRegressor(random_state=SEED)

search_space = {
    'xgb_clf__max_depth': Integer(2,30),
    'xgb_clf__subsample': Real(0.1, 1.0),
    'xgb_clf__colsample_bytree': Real(0.1, 1.0),
    'xgb_clf__colsample_bylevel': Real(0.1, 1.0),
    'xgb_clf__reg_alpha': Real(1.0, 100.0),
    'xgb_clf__reg_lambda': Real(1.0, 100.0),
    'xgb_clf__n_estimators': Integer(10, 1000),
    'xgb_clf__learning_rate': Real(0.01, 0.1, prior='log-uniform')
}

opt = BayesSearchCV(xgb_clf, search_space, cv=10, n_iter=30, scoring='roc_auc', random_state=SEED)
```

Moreover, I have written some code that should train my model row by row, where the rows are 2D numpy arrays saved in another directory and the labels, which are ages, are also saved in a separate folder. Since I want to train it row by row, according to the docs (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.fit) the `xgb_model` argument must be set. This requires my model to be saved, which I have tried in the code below:

```
import pickle

MODEL_PATH = "ML/model"  
os.makedirs(MODEL_PATH)
PATH_TRAIN_IMAGES = "ML/preprocessed_arrays/train"
PATH_TRAIN_LABELS = "ML/preprocessed_labels/train"
filename = MODEL_PATH + '/xgb_model.sav'

pickle.dump(opt, open(filename, 'wb'))

for instance_file, label_file in zip(os.listdir(PATH_TRAIN_IMAGES), os.listdir(PATH_TRAIN_LABELS)):
    instance = np.loadtxt(PATH_TRAIN_IMAGES + "/" + instance_file) 
    label = np.loadtxt(PATH_TRAIN_IMAGES + "/" + label_file)
    opt.fit(instance, label, xgb_model=filename)
    # save the model to disk
    pickle.dump(opt, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

Unfortunately, this code throws a `XGBoostError: basic_string::resize` error, which I do not understand.

I have already tried to make some research about this error but it seems to be a rare error.

How can I save my model, train it row per row, and avoid this error? Thanks in advance.